# Webassembly not supported on your browser - iOS

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, unity-game-engine, webassembly

Environment:

1. I made a web-app using cordova-phonegap supported with Angular
2. In my application there is an IFrame which is loading a WebGL Component Made with Unity3D
3. When I run the application on browser it works fine, loads the application and component perfectly on all browsers i.e., Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc
4. When I package the application to Android- there also it works perfectly no issues in loading the application or locally packaged WebGL files by Android app.
5. But When I package the application for iOS - It gives an error that "WebAssembly not supported by your browser".

P.S.: For website the webgl component is hosted on server but for mobile we are attaching files locally.

Some forums suggested to try WKWebView but doing so makes the entire app fail to load.

Answer (score 0):

The WKWebView is based on Safari and does not support by default WebGL2. https://caniuse.com/webgl2 but it should support WebGL1 https://caniuse.com/webgl

It seems like Unity supports WebGL 1 and WebGL 2. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-graphics.html So, try to build it with WebGL 1.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1454045/how-to-make-webgl-export-work-in-all-browsers.html

If that works, you could build it to WebGL 1 for ios and with WebGL  2 for android.
But off course some things might not work very good in WebGL 1.

[Image from the Unity forum about WebGL settings for Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYTpL.png)